# How do different buffer strategy sizes affect performance?

Tags: java, image

In java, in the Canvas class, I heard someone explain once that a larger bufferstrategy is more efficient when you go from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3, but above 3 it doesn't make a difference. Why doesn't bufferstrategy size above 3 make a significant speed increase, and how does the increase from createBufferStrategy(2) to createBufferStrategy(3) work?

Comment: I can see how two (or even three) buffers can help make an animation look smoother but I wonder, too, how the speed increase (if any) works.

Comment: Do you have the source to the explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a performance issue if and only if you want no tearing in the animation : in this case, you have to wait the system so that it has completed the display of the buffer before altering this buffer again.

So, with 1 buffer, you must wait, doing nothing.
With 2 buffer, you can write in the other buffer while the first is being displayed, but if you are fast enough, you might end up waiting before starting the next frame.
With 3 buffer, you can again do something instead of waiting.

It is less likely to have completed the drawing in the third buffer before the first one is fully displayed, thus the gain is very low above 3 buffer.

Please note that the more buffer you use, the more memory you need to host these buffer. This is not a problem on a regular computer, but it can be for phone apps.